# Lead-Acid battery connections

Tags: voltage, current, lead-acid, batteries

In a lead-acid battery we have 6 cells, each cell having positive and negative terminal. The negative terminal of the first cell from the right of the picture  connected to the positive terminal for the second cell, and so on. This mean that I connect the cells in series. Is it correct?

[image]

Could these cells be connected in parallel? If I connect them in parallel, I will get 2V, but the amperage should increase. Is that right?

Comment: You won't be able to put the cells of a general purpose SLA in parallel

Comment: *and if i connect them in parallel i will get 2v but the amperage will increase* You mean the maximum current increases: yes that is true. But as others also say: you cannot and should not try to do this. Why not ? Because SLA batteries can deliver **insanely** high currents already. Slight differences in voltages can make huge currents flow, damaging the battery and maybe the user as well.

Comment: @PlasmaHH. This is not true. Parallel connections are used to build large scale packs. This is done in trucking and marine applications all the time.

Comment: @JackCreasey Sure, but that would be done/build at the factory or during installation right ? By **professionals** who know what they're doing. Or maybe these are oldfashioned type SLA batteries which are connected but then filled (with acid) later ?

Comment: @JackCreasey: I have yet to come around and find an SLA where the assembly that connects two cells is not a solid chunk of lead or other metal that is hanged over the seperating plastic between the cells. I am however looking forward for your instructions on how to put these in parallel.

Comment: i understand the opinion of parallel connections but how about series connection of the cells , am i thinking right ?

Comment: If you had a 12v car battery, then sawing it into 6 individual cells would be mechanically impractical. If you had 6 separate cells, then you could connect them in series for 12v, parallel for 2v, or series/parallel for 4v or 6v (exercise for the reader how to do those).

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Within a single battery you will not find paralleled cells (typically). But larger scale battery packs such as marine, railway and trucking applications connect batteries is series and parallel.

Comment: @FakeMoustache. Providing the batteries are the same chemistry and Ah rating what problems exist in connecting in parallel?   None I'd suggest. When dealing with any high current or high voltage application one would always hope the people are professional, but what does that mean exactly? We quite casually jumper batteries in cars when needed....would you ban this because the batteries are different sizes and the consumer is not a professional?? Would you require licensed electricians to be the only ones who can do this?

Comment: @JackCreasey: So please tell me, how can I convert my 24V SLA to a 12V SLA with parallel cells?

Comment: @PlasmaHH. You typically can't convert an existing multi cell battery unit to parallel cells...you can however connect two SLA 12 V batteries together in parallel. The OP did not ask about SLA batteries ...he asked about LA cells which if individual could of course be connected in series or parallel.

Comment: @JackCreasey: around here, the difference between commercial LA and SLA batteries is just that the latter have no access to the acid, and are by far the more common one. Also those that give you access to the acid are usually exactly the same: the cathode of one cell is the same piece as the anode of the other. It would make no sense from a manufacturers pov to make the cell "reconfigurable"

Comment: @PalsmaHH. I totally agree with you, if you buy a modern SLA multi cell battery you won't be able to configure individual cells. However I have seen many UPS installations that use these individual cells: http://www.rathboneenergy.com/images/battery_hawker/cyclon_kit_1.jpg   ....it's still an SLA, but clearly can be used to build either series or parallel battery packs.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.
You connect battery cells in series to increase the voltage.
You connect battery cells in parallel to increase current capability.

There is no problem with either series or parallel connection.
http://www.atbatt.com/sealed-lead-acid-batteries/connecting-your-sla-batteries-together

Rules About Battery Configurations
When configuring batteries in Series or Parallel; batteries should match Voltage, Capacity, State of Charge and Relative Age for safety and best performance.

Series - In Series configuration or series leg of series/parallel configuration, batteries should be as identical as possible.

Parallel - In Parallel configuration or parallel legs of series/parallel configuration, battery voltages MUST be identical, but battery capacity, state of charge, and relative age can vary moderately from one parallel leg to another.

Connection Engine Cranking Batteries the CCA (cold cranking amps) are multiplied by the number of parallel connections. This is also true with amp-hour capacity in deep cycle application.

Comment: so actually they connect the positive terminal of one cell to the negative terminal of the other cell and from this combination i can get 12v

Comment: Yes - A 12 volt lead-acid battery consists of six 2 volt cells connected in series.  The same technique can be used with other types of cell to make a higher voltage battery.  The common 9 volt rectangular battery consists of six 1.5 vot cells in series.